# Why wouldn't institutions sell their stock during a short squeeze?

Tags: stock-markets

I was looking at one of the securities that has been short squeezed and I noticed that none of the major funds (like fidelity) have sold any shares during the price increase (its up 300%). Why would they not sell stock during a squeeze when the price is high?

Comment: They probably can't sell them because they have been lending them to a short seller.

Comment: @Manziel - Lending shares to shorters does not prevent one from selling your shares.

Comment: It's a good question.  You would think that any fund manager who owned shares below $20 before the short squeeze would have the good sense to sell those shares after they appreciated so much.  OF, nabbing $500 is a stretch but $100?, $200?, $300? adds a lot of bottom line performance for the year.

Comment: According to news reports, at least one institution (MUST Asset Management) has done just that, as have several people in GameStop management: https://www.marketwatch.com/story/large-gamestop-shareholder-must-asset-management-sold-off-its-stake-2021-01-28  The real question is why institutions would be holding shares of a failing business like GameStop in the first place.

Comment: Black Rock holds GME shares through their S&P Small Cap ETF. Seems to me they just bought the shares to track the updated index.

Comment: I didn't see any institutional trades last time I  checked that were recent

Comment: @BobBaerker If I understand it correctly, institutions that sell their lended stocks will trigger an automated buying order for the short seller first, the stocks will be returned and only then they can sell them. So selling larger portions of GME shares will reduce their potential market. That does not mean that t would not make sense, they will definitely able to buy them back later at a much lower price ;)

Comment: @Manziel - How does an institution `trigger an automated buying order for the short seller first` and what's your sourcing for this understanding?

Comment: I think it was in one of the recent GME threads where someone mentioned that the broker will automatically liquidate your position if the lending is canceled which should naturally happen if the original owner wants to sell his shares. However, maybe I am just thinking too normal for todays financial market and it is enough if the borrower covers his position in the near future

Comment: Is OP certain that the holdings of the fund are updated daily? The premise of the question is that OP is certain that the fund hasn't taken action, but OP may be consulting old information.

Comment: I guess they aren't on my broker or yahoo